# Where i can edit a text in wordpress that seemingly isn't in code?

Tags: wordpress, variables, product

My problem is I'm currently working on a wordpress site using woocomerce. I made a variable product and its generated a dropdown. The problem is before the dropdown its "generating" a text saying " … do dropdown …. " which is nowhere in the code. Not even the theme files or even in the database. i Provide some screenshot for the HTML code.

[I think its in the css ::after content"" but i cant find it anywhere.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTXLf.png)

I dont want to even show anything so a simple display:none would be nice but i cant select in css.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is definitely not CSS::after. `pseudo elements` are not displayed like `DOM elements` and are not displayed in the HTML code enclosed in the attached image. You probably have a code or plugin for variable products that is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

The text could be in either:

**The code base** - You can do a search in files on linux server by:

```
grep -noir "do dropdown"
```

**Or the database** - You can do an export of the database and then search the export with a text editor locally to find the table it is stored in. This will give you a lead on how you can change it.

Comment: I downloaded the entire database and find nothing like that. I also searched in my cpanel console but neither it worked.

Comment: Zip the website up in cPanel file manager. Download it > extract to local > open the folder in vscode/sublime text and do a find in all files search.

Comment: I downloaded it , still no luck. I think its generated in a javascript file. Maybe its linked from an eternal file. Is there any way to see the origin of the text in chrome devtools ?